# Is it possible to propagate a transaction through different EJB 3.1 and several database servers?

Tags: java, transactions, ejb

The problem is this, I have three EJB, the EJB_A have connection to the server database 1, the EJB_B have connection to the server database 2 and the third EJB_C which is responsible for calling the first two.

When there is an error in the EJB_A or EJB_B only rollback is done in the EJB where there is error, on the other EJB saved properly done, eventhough it should propagate the rollback to the two EJB.

EJB_C:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
@TransactionManagement( TransactionManagementType.BEAN )
public class EJB_C {

    private EJB_A ejbA;
    private EJB_B ejbB;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        Context context = null;
        try {
            context = new InitialContext();
            this.ayudanteSessionBean = (AyudanteSessionBean) context.lookup("java:global/Trans1/Trans1DBA/EJB_A");
            this.ayudanteSessionBean = (AyudanteSessionBean) context.lookup("java:global/Trans1/Trans1DBA/EJB_B");
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(OrquestadorSessionBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public void saveTwoEJBs(EntityA, a, EntityB b){
        try{
            ejbA.save(a);
            ejbB.save(b);
        }catch (Exception ex) {

        }
    }
}
```

EJB_A:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class EJB_A {
    @PersistenceContext( unitName = "persistA" )
    private EntityManager em;

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public void guardarAmigo(EntityA a){
        em.persist(a);
    }
}
```

EJB_B:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class EJB_B {
    @PersistenceContext( unitName = "persistB" )
    private EntityManager em;

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public void guardarAmigo(EntityB b){
        em.persist(b);
    }
}
```

Could you help me?

Comment: You are not creating transaction in EJB_C, it is BMT now. Either create it manually using `UserTransaction` object, or change to CMT by removing `@TransactionManagement( TransactionManagementType.BEAN )` or switching to `@TransactionManagement( TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)`

Comment: Why are you interested in bean managed transactions while using EJBs? You should be using container managed transactions unless bean managed transactions are explicitly needed - you may have to dump business logic on other than the service layer for some unclear reasons, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to make it work you will need to setup distributed transactions (XA) properly:

1. Check that all datasources are XA-ready. Typically this means different jdbc driver class name and different type of connection pool during setup.
   The process is vendor-specified, but always described in documentation of your application server.
2. You need to remove annotation:

   @TransactionManagement( TransactionManagementType.BEAN )

to let your container (actually his transaction broker) to manage transactions instead of bean.
3. You need to add @TransactionAttribute annotation on method saveTwoEJBs :

```
 @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public void saveTwoEJBs(EntityA, a, EntityB b)
```

4. It's not required but there is no reason to lookup EJB beans via JNDI context, just inject them via @EJB annotation:

   ```
   @EJB
   private EJB_A ejbA;
   @EJB
   private EJB_B ejbB;
   ```

Some links to go:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/ejb30/examples.html
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/servtran001.htm
http://entjavastuff.blogspot.ru/2011/02/ejb-transaction-management-going-deeper.html

Comment: Thanks to all for the information, it has been very useful